# Selecting records with total greater then specified value over specified time interval

Tags: sql, select, time, sum, cumulative-sum

This is for Check Cashing business.

I have a table of checks cashed:

```
CustomerID, CustomerName, DateTimeCashed,      CheckAmount,  CheckFee, CheckPaypot    
00100       John Doe      01/01/2017 12:40:30      1000         20        980
00200       John Smith    01/02/2017 13:24:45      2000         40        1960
..................
```

There are thousands of records like this.

I need to build a query which would return all records where total CheckPaypot for each Customer cashed in any 24 hour period exceeds 10000.

I know how to do this if a 24-hour interval is defined as a day from 12:00 AM to 11:59 PM.

```
Select * from (
Select CustomerID, CustomerName, DateTimeCashed, CheckAmount, CheckFee, CheckPaypot,
(Select sum(ch.CheckPaypot) from Checks ch 
where 
ch.CustomerID = c.CustomerID and CONVERT(date, cn.DateTimeCashed) = CONVERT(date, c.DateTimeCashed)
) as Total from Checks c) x
where x.Total > 10000
```

But the requirement is that the time interval is floating meaning that beginning and ending can be anything
as long as the length of the time interval is 24 hours. So of the Customer cashed 3 checks: 1 check in the afternoon
and 2 checks before noon of the next day and total of these checks is over $10000, they all must be included in the result.

Thank you,
lenkost.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Is there a unique id for each row?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   CustomerID,
   SUM(CheckPaypot) 
FROM
   tb_previsao 
WHERE
   DateTimeCashed > DateTimeCashed - INTERVAL '1' DAY 
GROUP BY
   CustomerID 
HAVING
   SUM(CheckPaypot) > 10000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'll have to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
  FROM (

SELECT outer_ch.*,
       (SELECT SUM(checkpayout)
          FROM checks inner_ch
         WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR, inner_ch.datetimecashed, outer_ch.datetimecashed)
                 BETWEEN 0 AND 23
           AND inner_ch.customerid = outer_ch.customerid) AS running_sum_checkpayout
  FROM checks outer_ch

       )
 WHERE running_sum_checkpayout > 10000
```

I say "unfortunately" because correlated subqueries are necessarily inefficient as they execute a separate subquery for each row in the result set.  If this doesn't perform well enough, try to avoid doing a full table scan for each of these subqueries, e.g. by putting an index on `customerid`.

Comment: This query will return running total for the last 24 hours for all rows for each customer. 
I need to return only the rows where the total of the surrounding transactions in a range of 24 hours exceeds $10000. 
Surrounding transactions meaning is the time distance between the first and last transaction in a block is less than 24 hours.
In other words, if the record is a part of 24 hours block where the total is over $10000, it must be included in the result.

Thank you, lenkost.

Comment: As stated in the original answer, you'll need to `SELECT FROM` the output of the query `WHERE running_sum_checkpayout > 10000` to get the result you're looking for.  I modified the answer to include this.